# EVO PDF Convertor: Can you download to PDF AND open the web page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, evo

I am using EVO PDF to combine multiple web pages into a single PDF.  The code below shows how it works...and it works.  If I comment out the section with `System.Web.HttpResponse` and just put `Response.Write(htmlCodeToConvert);` it will show both web pages on a single web page and there is no PDF download.

What I really want to do is both - I want to have the single, combined web page appear, and have the PDF download prompt appear as well.  I can get one or the other to work, but not both at the same time.  Is this possible?

```
  StringWriter htmlStringWriter = new StringWriter();

  Server.Execute("Page1.aspx", htmlStringWriter);
  Server.Execute("Page2.aspx", htmlStringWriter);

  string htmlCodeToConvert = htmlStringWriter.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
  htmlStringWriter.Close();

  // get the pdf bytes from html string
  byte[] pdfBytes = pdfConverter.GetPdfBytesFromHtmlString(htmlCodeToConvert);

  // send the PDF document as a response to the browser for download
  System.Web.HttpResponse response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
  response.Clear();
  response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
  response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", String.Format("attachment; filename=MyFile.pdf; size={0}", pdfBytes.Length.ToString()));
  response.BinaryWrite(pdfBytes);
  response.End();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you initially open the only page with content, let it be page1.aspx, without download? And when it's loaded, start download with javascript like window.open("page2.aspx");

Comment: Your solution is not exactly what I need, but it got me thinking about something similar that worked.  I load the combined pages into one then use window.location and javascript for the body onload event.  That redirects to a page that does the pdf download.  Thanks for the jumpstart idea.